# Clock() not working as expected; avoiding IO

Tags: c, file, hash

I am writing a program that reads in a large file (44GB - 63GB) 1MB at a time, and then I am hashing that 1MB. However, I would like to see how long it takes to perform those hashes

I am not interested in how long it takes to read in a file 1MB at a time, only concerned about the hash performance time. Currently I am using a very basic/generic hash function

Any ideas on where I start and end the time for the clock?

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define HASH_PRIME 65551// prime number for hash table

// generic hash function
static unsigned short hash_Function(char *hash_1MB)
{
    unsigned short hash;
    int i = 0;
    while(hash_1MB[i]!='\0')//each char of the file name
    {
        hash += (unsigned short)hash_1MB[i];//add it to hash
        i++;
    }
    return hash%HASH_PRIME;//mod hash by table size
}

int main()
{
    struct stat fileSize;
    char *buffer;

    FILE *fp;
    clock_t start, stop;
    double duration;
    char fname[40];

    printf("Enter name of file:");
    fgets(fname, 40, stdin);
    while (fname[strlen(fname) - 1] == '\n')
    {
        fname[strlen(fname) - 1] = '\0';
    }

    // handle file, open file, and read in binary form
    fp = fopen(fname, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open %s for reading\n", fname);
        exit(1);
    }

    stat(fname, &fileSize);
    size_t size = fileSize.st_size;
    printf("Size of file: %zd\n", size);

    buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(*buffer)*1000*1000);

    unsigned long long counter = 0;
    // read in 1MB at a time // & start timing how long it takes to perform the hash
    start = clock();
    clock_t total = 0;
    while (fread(buffer, sizeof(*buffer), (1<<20), fp) == (1<<20)) 
    {
    start = clock();
    hash_Function(buffer);  
    counter++;
    total += (clock() - start);
    }

    //free(buffer);

     fclose (fp); // close files

     duration = (double)((stop - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

     printf("Counter: %llu\n", counter); // how many MB were hashed
     printf("Hashing took %.2f seconds\n", (float)duration);
     return 0;
}
```

Also my results are not coming out as expected, the first file I analyzed was 1,961,893,364bytes large so there should be at least 1,961MB that were hashed

But when I print out my counter to check that the correct amount of MB's were hashed I only get 1871

Here are my results:

```
$ gcc one_mb.c
$ ./a.out
Enter name of file:v.10.nc
Size of file: 1961893364
Counter: 1871
Hashing took 0.00 seconds
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

///// Results w/ (1000*1000)

```
Enter name of file:v.13.nc
Size of file: 15695146912
Counter: 15695
Hashing took 18446744.00 seconds
```

////// Results w/ 1 << 20

```
Enter name of file:v.13.nc
Size of file: 15695146912
Counter: 14968
Hashing took 18446744.00 seconds // why this long?!?!? It didn't take 30mins
```

///// Replace while loop with for loop

```
// generic hash function
static unsigned short hash_Function(char *hash_1MB)
{
    unsigned short hash;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < (1 << 20); i++)
    {
        hash += (unsigned short)hash_1MB[i];//add it to hash
    }

    return hash%HASH_PRIME;//mod hash by table size
}
```

Comment: Your counter is counting in MiB and not MB. (1024*1024 bytes instead of 1000*1000)

Comment: Perfect, that fixed the problem, I'll edit right now, thanks

Comment: I would float the `(stop - start)` before you do the division.

Comment: I have a feeling it won't hash the last part of the file, unless it's exactly 1MB long.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, it probably won't but I am not too concerned about that. However, so I have to free the buffer every time I finish with the hash after one 1mb ? I commented it out because I wasn't sure if I had too or not

Comment: Note that your timing includes the time it takes to read the file because the `fread()` calls are between the start and end calls to `clock()`.  However, trying to split things up with the timing properly bracketing your hashing (and then accumulating the numbers so generated) may not be very reliable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take your time stamps inside your while loop and keep a sum of them to avoid timing the file IO.

```
start = clock();
clock_t total = 0;
while (fread(buffer, 1<<20, (1<<20), fp) == (1<<20)) 
{
    start = clock();
    hash_Function(buffer);  
    counter++;
    total += (clock() - start);
}
```

Notice I changed 1000*1000 to 1<<20 so it's actually the size of a MB.

Also make sure you alloc the buffer correctly for at least 1 MB.

```
buffer = (char*) malloc(1<<20);
```

The following would evaluate to (size of char) * 1000 * 1000 = 1000 * 1000 which would not work.

```
buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(*buffer)*1000*1000);
```

Also, when you do sizeof(*buffer), this returns the size of a char as well (1 byte). See the updated fread.

Comment: Thanks! But I tried that and my counter is not incremented?

Comment: I have posted my new results with the updated code you gave me

Comment: Did you change this? duration = (double)((stop - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

Comment: Since I already know that the hash function will only hash 1MB, do you think I could use a for loop such as what I updated?

Comment: If you notice, I get the same clock every time, even with the counter of the MB's being lower; do you happen to know why?

Comment: What is the resolution of the clock?  ms? us?

Comment: you have a great point; I am not sure? How would I find that out? I am going to look at some documentation for that; it would make a huge difference if it were milli or micro

Comment: I am thinking micro sounds most reasonable right now